# cli commands for partioning HDD

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount

I tried to mount an external HDD but, It seems that there's no partition in there.

```
fdisk -l
```

shows that

> Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors

but there's no /dev/sda1 or sda2 etc.

Could you tell me CLI command for making it to /dev/sda1 as a whole?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the fdisk tool example would be something like the following

```
fdisk /dev/sda
#### In fdisk #####
o  #blanks out drive
n  # creates a new partition
<enter> #partition number
<enter> #first sector
<enter> #last sector (enter assuming you only want a single partition
w       # writes all the changes
#### end fdisk ####
fdisk -l  #This is a check to see you made lasting changes
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1  #format the filesystem
```

hope this helps